# c++ rvalue move semantics, questions about streaming

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

A couple questions about semantics and performance:

```
x = 0;
While (x < 10) {
  std::cout << "Some text here to send to cout";
  ++x;
}
```

Im using gcc 4.7, Should the text to stream be wrapped inside of a std::move?

Like this:

```
   x = 0;
    While (x < 10) {
      std::cout << std::move("Some text here to send to cout");
      ++x;
    }
```

And while I am asking, is it better in cases like this to just make the string static like:

```
x = 0;
While (x < 10) {
  static const char* s = "Some text here to send to cout";
  std::cout << s;
  ++x;
}
```

Comment: All that's being passed in is a pointer, anyway.

Comment: Why do you expect the move to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving a string literal won't really do you much good: It will yield a pointer in any case and this pointer will be passed by value. With respect to making the string literal static, I would expect that it make no difference at all.

Comment: thanks alot, is this all because of compiler optimizations? Seems that making a string over and over would be slower than having it in static memory.

Comment: @bryansammon Doesn't have anything to do with optimizations. No strings are being created over and over - no std::string objects involved here, and the string literal already is in static memory.

Comment: oh ok, I see, so if it was a std::string, would that make any difference?

Comment: If you were creating `std::string` object that would be quite inefficient but it still wouldn't make any difference: the output operator for `std::string` takes its argument by `const&`. Move semantics are mostly useful when passing object around by value.

Answer (score 1):

No and no. There is no any difference for `operator<<` whether its `const char *` argument is rvalue or lvalue: in the latter case the standard lvalue-to-rvalue (pure conceptual) conversion will be automatically applied before it gets passed to `operator<<`.